# "column ambiguously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I'm totally having a hard time on comprehending SQL this semester. I'm really not confident on the knowledge I have in SQL and I'm trying to work on this exercise where it says:

A SELECT statement to retrieve a list of employees with  the columns `DEPARTMENT_ID , DEPARTMENT_NAME , FULL_NAME, JOB_TITLE`  where  FULL_NAME is the First name and Last name concatenated with a space between them  for those employees that  their  Job title contains the word 'Sales'. The list must be sorted by   job title and department name.

So far, I came up with this

```
SELECT department_id, 
    department_name, 
    first_name || ' ' || last_name as Full_name, 
    job_title
FROM departments d, employees e, jobs j
WHERE d.department_id=e.department_id 
HAVING job_title LIKE '%Sales%';
```

and the error says:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select department_id, department_name, first_name || ' ' || last_name as Full_name, job_title
from departments d, employees e, jobs j
where d.department_id=e.department_id 
having job_title like '%Sales%'
Error at Command Line:1 Column:8
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any tips and help will do.

Comment: And change `HAVING` to `AND`; `HAVING` is like `WHERE`, but for aggregate expressions, like SUM()s and COUNT()s.

Answer (score 6):

"Column 8" in your command is the eighth character, the `department_id` field.  You're SELECTing the column `department_id` from two tables which both have that column; it's ambiguous because the parser sees two possible values for `department_id` (the one from `departments` and the one from `employees`), *even though we know based on your WHERE clause that those values will be identical.*  You have to pick one:

```
select d.department_id, ...
```

Comment: thanks that really helped me understand so what i did was this                                                           select departments.department_id, 
employees.department_id, departments.department_name, employees.first_name || ' ' || employees.last_name as full_name, job_title
from departments, employees, jobs
where job_title like '%Sales%';                                                                                                                              now, the thing is that it outputs like at least 5000 rows i must be missing something

Comment: @user2145903 You took out "where d.department_id=e.department_id" so now it's pulling all the rows.

Comment: ok thanks so what i did was implemented where  employees.department_id=departments.department_id
and job_title like '%Sales%'
order by job_title, full_name asc; it narrowed it down into 212 rows but the problem now is the reason why its 212 is because its duplicated it should be less than 212 rows. is there any other statement i could apply to remove duplication?

Comment: i also tried using DISTINCT and still shows me 212rows

Comment: In the SQL still above, you haven't got a join to the jobs table, so it's probably duplicating entries for every job.

Answer (score 3):

Specify whether it's e.department_id or d.department_id (etc) for the selected fields